# Linux - Wine - is it possible to force locale + date/time format?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, locale

I would like to run some sensor software using Wine and serial port. However, this SW strictly requires exact date/time settings to work correctly.

I created a new account in KDE (running Kubuntu 13.04) and set the locale to US English. However, although I deleted *.wine* folder, Wine still seems to use Czech locale or at least some settings. As I do not want to damage my default system locale settings, I run the program using:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 wine program.exe
```

But the problem with date/time format remains. I need dd/mm/yy and time in hh:mm:ss - the same as uses Windows to make the program work properly.

is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to run `wine regedit`, and edit the appropriate keys (`sShortDate`, `sTimeFormat`) in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
```

Exit `regedit` and check that settings were saved with

```
wine regedit /E - 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International'
```